# Suggest a BDD testing framework for Node JS on Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, maven, bdd

My team is working on web application with rich HTML5 client and RESTfull server. Although our server-side code is a typical Java stack we use Node JS in our build process. Notably for CoffeeScript compilation, jsHint, and script minification.

I'd like to introduce automated testing for the client-side code and i need to pick a BDD framework. One note is that our application is deployed on Windows and we use it for development as well. So I'm worried whether a particular BDD framework would play along nicely with Windows version of Node JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say something about its window compatibility, but there are two BDD frameworks that you can use with automatic testing in jenkins: Jasmine trough the [Jasmine maven plugin](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-maven-plugin) and [BusterJs](http://busterjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in testing client side code, as it is in the browser, take a look at [ZombieJS](http://zombie.labnotes.org/). Also [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) is a good testing framework, so you may want to mix the two of them together.

Answer (score 0):

[Yadda](http://github.com/acuminous/yadda) is also worth checking out. It lets you write true BDD tests as follows

```
Scenario: A bottle falls from the wall

Given 100 green bottles are standing on the wall
when 1 green bottle accidentally falls
then there are 99 green bottles standing on the wall
```

It plugs into other frameworks like Mocha, CasperJS and Zombie.